# Can I get HTML id from HTML code written in JSON String in IBM WATSON

Tags: json, html, ibm-watson

I have written HTML code inside a JSON object as a string, is there a way in which i can access the HTML id from there.

```
{

  "text":"<ol><li id='it_1'>Item1</li><li id='it_2'>Item2</li><li id='it_3'>Item3</li></ol>"

}
```

I want that whenever user is clicking any link in the inner list, i should get the id of it. In this scenario i have defined this case in IBM Watson, now my motive is  whenever user is clicking any of the links i need to trigger another case. But for that i need to check which one did he choose.

Comment: You can write a regular expression to match everything with an id. Try [here](https://regex101.com)

Comment: Umh ... you can't click a link which is a string, please get familiar with [JSON Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) and add the relevant code to your post, and also describe your problem in details. Furthermore, there's no links even in the posted HTML string ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DOMParser()`, `querySelectorAll()` and `map()` like the following way:

```js
var json = {
"text":"<ol><li id='it_1'>Item1</li><li id='it_2'>Item2</li><li id='it_3'>Item3</li></ol>"
}
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(json.text, "text/html");
var ids = [...doc.querySelectorAll('li')].map(el => el.id);
console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You first need to add that list elements into the DOM
2. Then you need to attach click event listeners to each of the `<li>` elements
3. Using that listener you can access the `id` and other attributes of that element

```js
var obj = {
  "text": "<ol><li id='it_1'>Item1</li><li id='it_2'>Item2</li><li id='it_3'>Item3</li></ol>"
};
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = obj.text;

var liElems = document.querySelectorAll('ol li');
for(var i=0; i<liElems.length; i++){
  liElems[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target.id);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```